# How to delete carriage return in every cell in excel?

Tags: c#, excel, cell

I use this code for deleting carriage return from every cell in excel:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cells = reportSheet.Cells;
 cells.Replace("\n", "",
               Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,
               Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, false,
               false, true, false);
```

I get a message:

> "Microsoft Office Excel cannot find any data to replace. Check if your
>   search formatting and criteria are defined correctly. If you are sure
>   that matching data exists in this workbook, it may be on a protected
>   sheet. Excel cannot replace data on a protected worksheet."

Anybody know how to change carriage return in excel cell?

Comment: Try this: Read string from cell, replace "\n" in string, set string into cell

Comment: I suggest you experiment with **\r** or **\n\r**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If doing data entry in Excel and you press the Alt+Enter key, it will insert a linefeed character. However, if the input was written to the cell as a Windows line break (CR+LF), it will be displayed in Excel exactly the same way.

The safest way to ensure all line breaks are replaced is to cycle through all possibilities and replace each:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cells = reportSheet.Cells;
// Cycle through each newline code and replace.
foreach (var newline in new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" })
{
    cells.Replace(newline, "",
                  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, // Use xlPart instead of xlWhole.
                  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, false,
                  false, true, false);
}
```